# How to use MonkeyDevice.instrument?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

HI guys,
I'm trying to run one of my test instrumentation from my MonkeyRunner script.  Unfortunately I can't get it to work.  I've tried calling MonkeyDevice.instrument with different variations of the parameters but had no luck.

I've tried

device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
device.instrument("android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner")
device.instrument("com.myTestPackage.myTestClass")
device.instrument("com.myTestPackage/.myTestClass")
device.instrument("myTestClass")

None of these throw and error but they don't run the test either.  I can run my instrumentation via Dev Tools or though Android Junit Test so I know it works.

So can someone tell me the correct to use this method?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using wrong arguments. This script, which I named `instrumentation.mr`, helps you to use the right ones.
Invoke it using you target package name.

```
#! /usr/bin/env monkeyrunner

import sys
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner

PLI = 'pm list instrumentation'

def usage():
    print >>sys.stderr, "usage: intrumentation.mr target-package"
    sys.exit(1)

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        usage()

    pkg = sys.argv[1]

    print "waiting for connection..."
    device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

    print "running istrumentation for %s" % pkg
    for (i, t) in map(lambda l: l.split(), device.shell(PLI).splitlines()):
        if t == '(target=%s)' % pkg:
            print device.instrument(i.split(':')[1], { 'wait':True })['stream']
            return

    print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: instrumentation for %s not found" % pkg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For example:

```
$ instrumentation.mr com.example.aatg.tc
```

prints:

```
waiting for connection...
running istrumentation for com.example.aatg.tc

Test results for InstrumentationTestRunner=...............................
Time: 39.932

OK (31 tests)
```

Comment: Thanks for the script.  I will try to integrate it into what I'm doing.  "pm list instrumentation" helped me work out what the classname was supposed to be so I could run the test.  Would have never guessed that in a million years.

Answer (score 1):

The [MonkeyDevice.instrument(string class, dictionary args)](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/MonkeyDevice.html#instrument) maps onto the [InstrumentationTestRunner commands](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestRunner.html).  The Android documentation has some good info on the instrumentation command, [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html#RunTestsDevice).

What the documentation does NOT tell you is how to specify args.  I found that in the android source code.  See [AdbChipDevice line 483](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/8dd0bc70cb283db5d38bfaa15f9cbb3948f02324/chimpchat/src/com/android/chimpchat/adb/AdbChimpDevice.java).  Here's a copy and paste of the code:

```
   482     @Override
   483     public Map<String, Object> instrument(String packageName, Map<String, Object> args) {
   484         List<String> shellCmd = Lists.newArrayList("am", "instrument", "-w", "-r");
   485         for (Entry<String, Object> entry: args.entrySet()) {
   486             final String key = entry.getKey();
   487             final Object value = entry.getValue();
   488             if (key != null && value != null) {
   489                 shellCmd.add("-e");
   490                 shellCmd.add(key);
   491                 shellCmd.add(value.toString());
   492             }
   493         }
   494         shellCmd.add(packageName);
   495         String result = shell(shellCmd.toArray(ZERO_LENGTH_STRING_ARRAY));
   496         return convertInstrumentResult(result);
   497     }
```

So the following python monkey code:

```
params = dict()
params['size'] = 'small'
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
device.instrument('com.mycompany.myapp/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner', params)
```

Is equivalent to the following command:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -r -e size small com.mycompany.myapp/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```