# how to use MonkeyDevice.broadcastintent() and MonkeyDevice.instrumentate()

Tags: monkeyrunner

How does one use `MonkeyDevice.broadcastintent()` and `MonkeyDevice.instrumentate()`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `MonkeyDevice.instrument()`? If yes then the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690173/how-to-use-monkeydevice-instrument) might be of use.

For `MonkeyDevice.bordcastintent()` I would take a look at the android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/MonkeyDevice.html#broadcastIntent). Personally I've found that using the shell works much better than bordcastintent. For example if I wanted to use the shell to bordcast an intent to add a contact I would use `device.shell("am start -a android.intent.action.INSERT -t vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact -e name 'Donald Duck' -e phone 555-1234")`.